# passing a block into create method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a method which will work like this one

```
def create_new_car(salon)
    Car.create name: salon.offer.name, description: salon.offer.description, photo: salon.offer.photo, dealer_id: salon.dealer_id
end
```

but i want to keep it DRY. is there a way to pass those attributes by, i dont know, iterating through array of attributes by passing a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to [`create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class/):

```
def create_new_car(salon)
    Car.create do |car|
        car.name = salon.offer.name
        car.description = salon.offer.description
        car.photo = salon.offer.photo
        car.dealer_id = salon.dealer_id
    end
end
```

You could also set some attributes as the first parameter and then pass a block:

```
    Car.create(name: salon.offer.name) do |car|
        car.description = salon.offer.description
        #...
    end
```

You can implement any logic you want inside that block to assign the `Car` properties, like this:

```
    attributes = ["name", "description", "photo", "dealer_id"]
    Car.create do |car|
        attributes.each { |a| car.send( "#{a}=", salon.offer.send(a) )
    end
```

Comment: this lat part of your answer is pretty much what i needed, only dealer_id shouldnt be in the attributes array, because it is not to be taken from offer but from salon. anyway, thx, it was good lead

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
array_of_attrbiutes = [{name: salon.offer.name...}, {name: }, {}...]    
 def create_new_car(array_of_attributes)  
  Car.create array_of_attributes
 end  
end
```

Please see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b15ce4a006756a0b6cacfb9593d88c9a7dfd8eb0/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L259